# Mudar conteúdo de um form sem precisar abrir outro no c#

Tags: c#

Eu gostaria de saber, como faço pra mudar o conteúdo do Form sem precisar abrir outro, quando eu clico em Criptografia por exemplo, o conteúdo muda sem precisar abrir outro Form. Como faço isso?

[image: Form]

Comment: você pode usar um tabControl, ou abrir os outros forms dentro desse principal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulando `UserControl`(s) você consegue criar um objeto herdado de `Control`. Assim, crie seu formulário neste `UserControl` e faça que funcione como um Form.

Após isso, crie um `Panel` cliente que irá exibir as páginas, e declare os controles como no exemplo abaixo:

```
public UserControlHome ucHome = new UserControlHome();
public UserControlCripto ucCripto = new UserControlCripto();
```

E crie este método para alterar o `Control` que está no `Panel` cliente `conteudo`:

```
public void AlterarConteudo(ref Control controle) {
    // considere 'conteudo' o Panel que irá ter os controles dentro
    conteudo.Controls.Clear(); // - remove os controles dentro do Panel
    { // altera propriedades do controle que irá ser colocado
        controle.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
    // adiciona o controle ao cliente
    conteudo.Controls.Add(controle);
}
```

E ao clicar no botão de Criptografia, chame o método com a expressão:

```
AlterarConteudo(ref ucCripto);
```

E para o botão Home:

```
AlterarConteudo(ref ucHome);
```

> Lembre-se de implementar um método para salvar informações nos controles ao serem [descartados](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457521/how-to-check-if-object-has-been-disposed-in-c-sharp).